# Flot chart's legend move to left side if css for table { width:100%}

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

Flot chart's legend move to left side if css for table { width:100%}.

Is that anything I can do if I want to maintain table { width:100%} since it is site-wide applied css?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXPWK/59/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Flot chart's parent element has an ID or a class, you could override the width for tables within that parent only, like this:

```
#placeholder table { width: 200px !important; }
```

This is really a hack, though; the limitations are obvious.

The real solution is to get rid of your existing rule.  A global table rule is a really bad idea, and this problem illustrates exactly why.  Sooner or later you'll run into the same thing again in a different context, and it might be much harder to fix.

The reason why your question is getting down-voted is because any serious web designer cringes when they hear that you have a global table rule.

You should solve the problem by either:

1. Give your tables classes, i.e. `<table class="myclass" ...>` and then put your 100% width in a `table.myclass` rule.
2. If your tables share a parent, give it a class and then use a rule like `.my-tables table` to affect only the tables in your area.

Comment: Not my fault to use it since I bought the software from developer company and I don't think I can change it myself since any update from that developer company will fail the efforts.